# NullPointerException thrown by code

Tags: java, design-patterns, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner, token

I have a task to read data from a file, format it and then output it to another .csv file. I'm testing my reading and I'm getting a null pointer and I can't seem to figure out why. Three classes and an interface are involved. I have the processor that is pulling data out a full record set at a time. Of course main that is compiling each record set into a series of `ArrayLists`. I also have a `Reader` that is reading data from the file one entry at a time.

Reader

```
public class CabRecordReader {
boolean moreRecords;
File inputFile;
Scanner in;

public CabRecordReader(String inputPath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    inputFile = new File(inputPath);
    in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    in.useDelimiter(",\n");
    moreRecords = true;
}

public boolean hasMoreRecords() {
    moreRecords = in.hasNext();
    return moreRecords;
}
public String getNextRecord() {
    String line;
    moreRecords = in.hasNext();
    if(moreRecords) {
        line = in.next();
        return line;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The processor

```
package edu.trident.Olliff.AcmeFileRead;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CabRecordProcessor implements CabRecord {

String output;
CabRecordReader reader;
RecordType recType;
Date recDate;
String recID;
double recValue;
double recGalCost;

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");

public CabRecordProcessor(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
    try {
        reader = new CabRecordReader(inputPath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not Found...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    output = outputPath;
}

public void readFullRecord() {
    try {
        recDate = formatter.parse(reader.getNextRecord());
        recID = reader.getNextRecord();
        recType = RecordType.valueOf(reader.getNextRecord());
        recValue = Double.parseDouble(reader.getNextRecord());
        if(recType == RecordType.valueOf("GAS")) {
            recGalCost = Double.parseDouble(reader.getNextRecord());
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("Error with the Date on " + recID);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("Error with the Type on " + recID);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("Getting this for some reason at " + recID);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean butWait() {
    return reader.hasMoreRecords();
}

@Override
public RecordType getType() {
    return recType;
}

@Override
public Date getDate() {
    return recDate;
}

@Override
public String getCabId() {
    return recID;
}

@Override
public double getValue() {
    return recValue;
}

@Override
public double getPerGallonCost() {
    return recGalCost;
}

}
```

And the associated portion of main

```
ArrayList<String> cabIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    ArrayList<RecordType> types = new ArrayList<RecordType>();
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> gasCosts = new ArrayList<Double>();

    int tracker = 0;

    CabRecordProcessor processor = new CabRecordProcessor(inputPath, outputPath);

    while(processor.butWait()) {
        processor.readFullRecord();
        cabIDs.add(processor.getCabId());
        dates.add(processor.getDate());
        types.add(processor.getType());
        values.add(processor.getValue());
        if(processor.getType() == RecordType.valueOf("GAS")) {
            gasCosts.add(tracker,processor.getPerGallonCost());
        }
        tracker++;
    }
```

When I catch the `NullPointerException` it tells me that `recID` is `null`. It seems like `processor.butWait()` is not evaluating properly but I don't understand why not. Could you explain it to me?

example input

```
2014/02/19,CAR27,SERVICE,12
2014/02/15,CAR54,FARE,12
2014/02/15,CAR54,SERVICE,12
2014/02/16,CAR54,FARE,12
2014/02/19,CAR54,SERVICE,12
2014/02/18,CAR42,SERVICE,12
2014/02/16,CAR42,FARE,12
2014/02/19,CAR42,SERVICE,12
2014/02/14,CAR27,GAS,18,3.20
2014/02/14,CAR42,GAS,18,3.20
2014/02/20,CAR42,GAS,18,3.20
2014/02/16,CAR27,GAS,20,3.11
2014/02/16,CAR42,GAS,20,3.11
2014/02/14,CAR14,GAS,22,3.20
2014/02/15,CAR14,FARE,22
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code?  What is the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
 at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at edu.trident.Olliff.AcmeFileRead.CabRecord$RecordType.valueOf(CabRecord.java:1)
 at edu.trident.Olliff.AcmeFileRead.CabRecordProcessor.readFullRecord(CabRecordProcessor.java:34)
 at edu.trident.Olliff.AcmeFileRead.CabRecordMain.main(CabRecordMain.java:30)

Comment: Can you show me your full CabRecordProcessor code or just tell what is the line 34 in that class?

Comment: Sorry completely forgot to mention the language. And I have edited to include the full file for CabRecordProcessor

Comment: Hmm, it look like, that reader.getNextRecord in this line recType = RecordType.valueOf(reader.getNextRecord()); returns null. taking into account that you're stating that recID is also null, I would say, that the reader returns after the first read null

Comment: Can you add a sample input file pls

Comment: The problem is in the line recType = RecordType.valueOf(reader.getNextRecord()); It seems that the reader.getNextRecord() is returning null. But I'll need the input file to find where the error is

Comment: This input data does not work with your specified delimiter `",\n"`. If you want to read the whole line, then use `in.nextLine()` and `in.hasNextLine()`. (Edit: your program can still read that file, but it will read the whole file at once)

Comment: @LuisAlves I was able to determine by printing to the console the value of moreRecords when hasMoreRecords() is called, that only shows once so it is failing somewhere on the first line.

Comment: your `butWait` method only tests if there is at least `1` more record. Your `readFullRecord` requires `5` of them

Comment: @njzk2 How do I test if there are 5 more lines? .hasNextLine() also only checks for one entry right? --Tom fixed the initial null issue but I'm getting tons of IllegalArgumentException but I will make a seperate question for that if I need to. You mind making an official answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Tom ah, I misunderstood. Each individual entry needs to go to a different array. I suppose I could store each line as a string and then try and parse it internally but I want to know why this here isn't working. It should I would think

Comment: As a side note, `RecordType.valueOf("GAS")` should really be `RecordType.GAS`

Comment: @JoesphOlliff If I understand you correctly, than you will split the data by a `,` and `\n`. If this is the case, then use `useDelimiter("[,\n]")`. `,\n` describes a sequence of chars that will be used to split at (`a,b,\nc` will be `a,b`, `c`). `[,\n]` describes an amount of chars that will be used to split. The difference here is, that it will split on each single char: `a,b,\nc` will be `a`, `b`, `c`.

Comment: @Tom Complete success, that was the problem I was suppose to put brackets in. Please make this an official answer so that I can mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compiling all the snippets you pasted (http://ideone.com/f2nwnB, please post complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) next time to save other people's time...you missed `RecordType` `enum` and some other stuff there) I've found your error. You're using (probably due to a typo)

```
in.useDelimiter(",\n");
```

instead of

```
in.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
```

. Changing that should fix *one* of the problems you have. Also, you should improve your method's names (some of them are really awkward and nonstandard... `butWait()`? `hasMoreRecords()`, like in other place in your code, would be a lot better here) and use the enums properly (i.e. `RecordType.GAS` instead of `RecordType.valueOf("GAS")`).

Comment: Can you explain (or post a link that does) what SSCCE is? Please and thank you.

Comment: `After compiling all the snippets you pasted` ... you mean, `After reading Toms comment` :P. Good that we both found the problem and you spared me from writing the answer :D. +1

Comment: @Tom http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+minds+think+alike